# How can I refresh some parameters in a String?

Tags: java, string

I have a code like:

```
int q = 2;
int w = 3;
String str = "q = " + q + "\nw = " + w;

q++;
System.out.println(x+q);
```

Is it possible to refresh the q in str, so the Output is not q = 2, rather q = 3?

My actual String is a lot bigger, and has more Parameters.
It looks terrible, cause I have to use that piece in 5 different Methods.

Comment: No. Use a class, change a field, and create a method (not `toString()`) to output the finished string value

Comment: To "refresh the string" you can run `str = "q = " + q + "\nw = " + w;` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class that holds all parameters and generates a string for demand, something like:

```
class MyStringGenerator{
  private int q;
  private int w;
  setQ(int q ){
    this.q = q;
  }
  setW( int w ){
    this.w = w;
  }

  public String getMyString(){
    return String.format("q = %d \nw = %d", q, w);
  }
}
```

and

```
MyStringGenerator msg = new MyStringGenerator();
int q = 2;
int w = 3;
msg.setQ( q );
msg.setW( w );

String str = msg.getMyString();

q++;
System.out.println(x+q);
msq.setQ( q ); // set a new value of Q
String newString = msg.getMyString();
```

Comment: When you use `String#format`, when also use `%n` instead of `\n`.

Comment: @Tom, I don't understand your question, please clarify - I use %d as format secifiers, and also \n as a new line, it builds a string `q=value(new-line)w=value`, please refer to the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)

Comment: `\n` creates a new line, yes, but it isn't platform independent like `%n`, because the latter creates `\r\n` on Windows.

Comment: @Tom this question should be rather asked to @Gökhan, not to me, He is using `\n` in his question, which is not platform independent. Maybe a requirement of his project is to use '\n' ? I really don't know.

Comment: @kordirko Thank you, that already helped me :D, I am still learning all that, I didnt knew that with %n ^^

Comment: @kordirko You're the one who suggested `String#format`, not OP and `%n` is a placeholder in ... `String#format` (OP uses `System.out.println`), so there is no need to ask OP ;P.

Answer (score 1):

the variable str is immutable, you can't change it once it's been created